# UIImageView not displaying set image from UITableViewController

Tags: ios, uiimageview, imageview, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` with a list of image names. When a name is clicked, the URL of the image is set in the `ImageViewController` and then the the `UITableViewController` segues to the `ImageViewController` that contains a `UIImageView` (connected with an outlet). In the `ImageViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` I set the `UIImageView` to the image from the URL but when I run it on the simulator, only a black screen appears where the image should be.

*A little visual description of the segue (where -> means segue):*

- `ImageListTableViewController` –> ImageViewController(has `UIImageView`)

`ImageListTableViewController.m`

```
// The delegate here is the ImageViewController
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Show Image"]) {
        [self setDelegate:segue.destinationViewController];
    }
}
// getting URL and calling the protocol method (in ImageViewController) which sets
// the image as an @property
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *imageDict = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSURL *imageURL = [FlickrFetcher urlForPhoto:imageDict format:FlickrPhotoFormatLarge];
    NSLog([imageURL description]);
    [self.delegate imageListTableViewController:self withURL:imageURL];
}
```

`ImageViewController.m`

```
#import "ImageViewController.h"

@implementation ImageViewController

@synthesize image = _image;
@synthesize imageView = _imageView;

- (void)imageListTableViewController:(ImageListTableViewController *)sender 
                             withURL:(NSURL *)imageURL;
{
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    self.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle


// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView
{
  // nothing
}


// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.imageView setImage:self.image];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setImageView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

@end
```

Any ideas on what's going on?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really the right way to use a delegate.  Try this:
In `ImageViewController.h`:

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSURL *imageURL;
```

In `ImageViewController.m`

```
@synthesize imageURL;
```

Remove imageListTableViewController

Change `viewDidLoad`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    self.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}
```

Add to `viewDidUnload`:

```
[self setImageURL:nil];
```

Then in your `ImageListTableViewController.m`:
Change `prepareForSegue`:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Show Image"]) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSDictionary *imageDict = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSURL *imageURL = [FlickrFetcher urlForPhoto:imageDict format:FlickrPhotoFormatLarge];

        // Set the property on our Dest VC
        ImageViewController *ivc = segue.destinationViewController;
        ivc.imageURL = imageURL;

    }
}
```

Change your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"Show Image" sender:nil];
}
```

Make sure you have connected that Segue to the VC itself and not to the TableView.  If you don't that Segue will get fired before `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is fired.  In this case, it won't make a difference, but for real control - get in the habit of connecting to the VC and calling performSegue when needed.

Comment: Thanks a bunch ElJay, I'll try this when I get home. For future reference, when would be a proper time to use delegates? I'm following the Stanford lecture series and from what I could tell they were used in this way.

Comment: Delegates are a good way to tell a class that you have finished doing something.  They can be used to let a calling class know that something is finished and can pass objects back (like when you are logging a user in and need to pass back UserInfo).  They aren't really used (from my experience) to call forward to something.  The Stanford videos are great BTW.

Comment: Thanks. Okay, after trying this I'm still getting just a black screen. Also, it takes a lot longer to segue to the image. Thoughts?

Comment: If you zip that up and stick it on the public side of your dropbox account, I will check it out and tell ya what's wrong.

Comment: Much appreciated. I changed it back to my original code because when I used the new stuff everything seemed to be really laggy.
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13903949/How%20to%20use%20the%20Public%20folder.rtf

Comment: The link was to the How to use the public folder file.  Right click on the zipped project and copy the public link for the zip file :)

Comment: Haha, wow thats kind of embarrassing. 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13903949/Flickr%20Tops.zip

Comment: Here is my new code without the delegates. 
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13903949/Flickr%20Tops2.zip

Comment: Here ya go.  I don't know what was wrong with your project (it was corrupted, that's all I can tell).  It wouldn't recognize new classes added was one indication.

Comment: In any event, I created a new project and then migrated some stuff over.  I also created the project using the practices that I use (you will see how I structure things).  I also added in a custom class that I wrote to load web content async, and MBProgressHUD which helps to let the user know what is happening during image loading.  Feel free to contact me directly through www.irockios.com if you have any questions (I used the TabBar tutorial to create the storyboard btw). Here is the link to the zipped project.  Please dl today sometime.  http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3660978/FlickrTops_New.zip

Comment: Thanks again ElJay. I couldn't find any Contact Info on your site so I just posted somewhere (thinking it might send you an email).

Answer (score 0):

Try calling this method:

```
[self.imageView setImage:self.image];
```

in the -

```
(void)imageListTableViewController:(ImageListTableViewController *)sender 
                             withURL:(NSURL *)imageURL;
```